# Chrome App CSP violation after Dart/Polymer transform/compile to JavaScript

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer

Alright-- so there are a lot of similar questions regarding Polymer after `dart2js`. I am seemingly running into an issue that's specific to doing this but also running it as a Chrome app.

I have discovered that the outcome varies depending on the order of the transformers (which is expected).

Here's my results so far:

```yml
transformers:
- chrome
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/example.html
    csp: true
- $dart2js:
    csp: true
```

This works great in browser but fails when run as a Chrome app.

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` (in the example.html_bootstrap.dart.js file)

**From this point I am removing the `chrome` transformer because it's redundant.**

Now I will switch the order of the transformers:

```yml
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    csp: true
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/example.html
    csp: true
```

This fails when run in the browser.
Error: `example.html_bootstrap.dart.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

This also fails when run as a Chrome app (with the same error).

Now I try to replicate what the guys on the CDE team are doing. Taking out the $dart2js transformer entirely.
https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/master/ide/pubspec.yaml

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/example.html
    csp: true
```

This runs perfectly from the browser.

This fails when run as a Chrome app.

Error: blah blah violates CSP policy with `unsafe-eval`

Just to cover my bases I also tried this (fails CSP policy):

```yml
- chrome
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/example.html
    csp: true
```

and this (fails CSP policy):

```yml
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/example.html
    csp: true
- chrome
```

Comment: You're not alone in this. Do you see any difference between running in Dartium and Chrome(ium)?

Comment: A while ago I submitted https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21782, which seems related to your first error code, but not completely. I'm not making Chrome apps though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can omit the `chrome` transformer when you use Polymer and `$dart2js` should be the last transformer. 
[csp_fixer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/csp_fixer) is supposed to fix remaining issues.

Comment: Is this the same idea as the "Fix for CSP" option that CDE uses? Will be able to get back in to this on Monday for another round (and to mark answer). Thanks as usual Günter.

Comment: I don't know, but the creator of the package (Sungguk Lim) is a contributor to GDE and I guess it is related.