# CSP issues with Polymer 1.0.0 rc in Chrome App

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer

I am attempting to run a simple Dart Polymer app as a Chrome application.

My sample is based on code from https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart-patterns. I extracted one of the samples, placed it in my`web` directory, and copied dependencies and transformer configuration from the sample's pubspec.yaml. I added the `csp:true` flag to the `$dart2js` transformer. I then added a bare bones manifest and background.js to enable running the app as a Chrome App.

```
name: x_app_polymer_dart
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.18.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  browser:          ^0.10.0
  polymer:          ^1.0.0-rc.18
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.9
  web_components:   ^0.12.0
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    csp: true
```

Note that I am using the latest Polymer 1.0.0 release candidate.

My app runs fine when served by `pub serve` and loaded in a Chrome browser.

The code loads a Chrome app, runs, but generates a slew of CSP violation error messages. The `csp: true` flag seemingly has no effect on Dart compilation.

I noticed in other related question/answers such as [Chrome App CSP violation after Dart/Polymer transform/compile to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511346/chrome-app-csp-violation-after-dart-polymer-transform-compile-to-javascript), the `csp: true` flag was set on the Polymer transformer, but the 1.0.0 version does not support it.

Any suggestions as to how to force CSP safe compilation of my Dart code in this case?